# Extract function to standalone custom React component in react-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

My primary goal is to call fitBounds whenever a `FeatureGroup` is rendered in `react-leaflet` on initial load.

This renders correctly -

```
<Map>
  <LayersControl>
    {getLayers(groups)}
  </LayersControl>
</Map>


function getLayers(featureGroups: MyFeatureGroup[]){
  const showOnLoad = true;
  return featureGroups.map((group: MyFeatureGroup) => {
    const groupRef = createRef<FeatureGroup>();
    const { id, name, } = group;
    return (
      <LayersControl.Overlay checked={showOnLoad} key={id} name={name}>
        <FeatureGroup ref={groupRef}>
          <Layer {...group} />
        </FeatureGroup>
      </LayersControl.Overlay>
    );
  });
}
```

However, because it is using a function instead of React component, I don't have access to using React hooks.

The alternative that I tried does not work, even though it is the same code wrapped in a React component -

```
...same as above...

  return featureGroups.map((group: MyFeatureGroup) => (
    <ControlledGroup {...group} showOnLoad={showOnLoad} /> ///----- > ADDED THIS HERE
  ));


const ControlledGroup: React.FC<ControlledGroupProps> = (props) => {
  const groupRef = createRef<FeatureGroup>();
  const { map } = useLeaflet();
  /// -----> map is correctly defined here - injecting to all of the layers (LayersControl, FeatureGroup) does not solve the problem 
  const { showOnLoad, ...group } = props;
  useEffect(() => fitBounds(map, groupRef));  ///-----> Primary Goal of what I am trying to accomplish
  return (
    <LayersControl.Overlay
      checked={showOnLoad}
      key={group.id}
      name={name}
    >
      <FeatureGroup ref={groupRef}>
        <Layer map={map} {...group} />
      </FeatureGroup>
    </LayersControl.Overlay>
  );
};
```

I am a bit stumped, since this is the same code. The `getLayers` function returns a `ReactNode` in both cases. However, when moving to a standalone `ControlledGroup` component, it throws an error on render -

```
addOverlay is not a function
```

I tried creating a custom class component for react-leaflet, but the difficulty that I ran into there is that `createLeafletElement` returns a `Leaflet.Element`, whereas I am simply looking to return a `ReactNode`. That is, all of these are valid `react-leaflet` components already.

My questions - why does one work and the other does not? What is the correct/recommended way to convert this function to a renderable stand-alone React component?

Further, if there is an alternative pattern to calling fitBounds, that would be helpful as well.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Layers` share an inheritance with `Layers.Overlay`, the solution to the render error is to keep the Layers together and move the feature group to a standalone component.

This works as expected and allows me to call `useEffect` on the groupRef -

```
function getLayers(groups: MyFeatureGroup[]){
  return featureGroups.map((group: MyFeatureGroup) => {
    const { id, name, } = group;
   return (
///---> Keep the Overlay in the function here and extract just the FeatureGroup out
      <LayersControl.Overlay checked={showOnLoad} key={id} name={name}> 
        <ControlledGroup {...group}></ControlledGroup>
       </LayersControl.Overlay>
    );
}
```